# PowerShell Output into Batch Variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

My goal is to save and use the result of a PowerShell command in a variable in the batch script. The PowerShell comand is:

`-join ((1..12) | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })`

or

`(1..12 | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) }) -join ''`

I've several examples that use the FOR...DO statement. But I don't know why all of them can't make my goal work:

```
@echo off

1st try : for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "-join ((1..12) | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })" ') do set "var=%%a"
2nd try : for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell "-join ((1..12) | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })" ') do set "var=%%a"
3rd try : for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell /command "(1..12 | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) }) -join ''"') do set var=%%a
4th try : for /f "delims=" %%a in (' powershell /command "(1..12 | %{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) }) -join ''" ') do set "var=%%a"

echo %var%

pause
```

Can you please advise me what to do?.

Comment: In a batch file, the percent, _(`%`)_, character is special, and needs escaping. The escape method for that character is another percent character. Example: ```@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "-join ((1..12) | %%{ '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "var=%%G"```.

Comment: Time to switch to powershell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use and replace `%` by `ForEach-Object` alias `ForEach` from PowerShell Command :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Variable Value from Powershell Scipt with a Batch file
Set PsCommand="-join ((1..12) | ForEach { '{0:X}' -f (Get-Random -Max 16) })"
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Powershell -C %PsCommand%') do Set "Var=%%a"
echo My Variable Value from Powershell script is : [%Var%]
Pause
```